# How to insert many entities of different kind at once - App Engine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql

Let's say I get some data from the request:

```
taxi = self.request.get('taxi')
address = self.request.get('txtAddress')
name = self.request.get('txtName')
age = self.request.get('age')
```

Then I insert a 'student' entity:

```
rs_student = Student(name = name, int(age=15), 'whatever')
rs_student.put()
```

then I get these two entities with the above variables:

```
rs_address = db.get(address)
rs_taxi = db.get(taxi)
```

I must insert a new entity now:

```
rs_store = Store(address = rs_address.street, student = rs_student, 'blabla').put()
```

Finally, this would be the last step of the operation:

```
rs_last_step = LastStep(store = rs_store, rs_taxi).put()
```

But what if something goes wrong before reaching the last step, after some insert operations
were already made?... I don't want to make new Student or Store entities that will be useless unless the last step has been successfully completed.

How can I deal with this?

Comment: Im not familiar with gql but databases and orm frameworks generally know the concept of transactions allowing you to rollback changes if something went wrong or a user e.g pressed a cancel button in a form. Look it up.

Comment: Here' I'll make it super easy: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions